# Convert unixtime to DateTime immediately

Tags: c#

There was a problem converting unixtime to DateTime.

I am passing in parameter 1663869600 this is September 22, 22. But in the code, after instrumentation, I get the date 1/20/1970 6:11:09 AM.

Why is that ?

I will convert the date in the following ways:

```
DateTime start = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(request.StartTime).DateTime;
var startUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(start, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

and

```
DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var startUtc = dtDateTime.AddMilliseconds(request.StartTime).ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kMtwWJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unix time is number of seconds (not milliseconds) since the epoch (as [@Gus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535515/gus) correctly mentioned). So the solution is to use `FromUnixTimeSeconds` instead of `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` and `AddSeconds` instead of `AddMilliseconds`.

```
DateTime start = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1663869600).DateTime;
var startUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(start, DateTimeKind.Utc);

DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var startUtc2 = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(1663869600).ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, does unixtime Deal with leap seconds and following on does FromUnixTimeSeconds also deal with leap seconds?